VSCode Javascript Debugger does not stop at break point
Problem: I want to debug a simple js file with node.
Expected Result: THe debugger starts and stops at the break point. -> but the debugger does not stop at break-points and simply runs through the program until the end...: Does anybody know why? Here is my program and launch config as well as terminal output: 


